# concatenate data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I have a table data like this:

[image: Table structure]

I want to concatenate the data as below in postgresql:

[image: Desired Output]

I used query as below but there is a small problem:

```
select 
    Item,
    array_to_string(array_agg(Component) ,', ') AS Component,
    array_to_string(array_agg(Seller) ,', ') AS Seller
from tablename
group by Item
```

Its giving me below output:

[image: Giving output]

For item A2, its showing C89 two times, I want to show only one time.

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `distinct`, you also don't need `array_agg()`:

```
select item, 
       string_agg(distinct component, ',') as component,
       string_agg(distinct seller, ',') as seller
from tablename
group by item;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, sometimes you need to tell it how to order the distinct

```
select 
    Item,
    array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT Component ORDER BY Item DESC ) ,', ') AS Component,
    array_to_string(array_agg((DISTINCT Seller ORDER BY Item DESC) ,', ') AS Seller
from tablename
group by Item
```

Comment: The `order by item` is useless because of the  `group by item` which means all values that are aggregated will have the same value for the column `item`